# Hide specific elements using eq() and a for() loop?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to hide an input box if the preceding input box's value is the same e.g.

```
City     Id    Name

NY        1     James
NY        2     John
TOKYO     3     Jane
TOKYO     4     June
```

I want to hide the second NY and the second TOKYO (NB:only the city, the Id and Name should remain).

I am using the jQuery script below:

```
<script>

$(function(){

var tr_no = $('.city').length;

for(i=1; i<=tr_no; i++)  {

    if($(".city:eq("+i+")").val() == $(".city:eq("+i+++")").val()){

        $(".city:eq("+i+1+")").css({'display':'none'});

        }

    }


});

</script>
```

It is not working. Firebug Console does not return any errors.  Any help on how to continue this on jQuery will much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe instead of `i++` you mean `(i + 1)`? (In the `.city:eq()`, not the for loop)

Comment: I meant `$(".city:eq("+i+++")").val()`

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you really should store the result of `$(".city")` into a variable, then use the `.eq()` function (rather than the `:eq()` selector) to access elements at specific indexes. That will save you selecting those elements repeatedly.

Comment: Ok changed it to `.city:eq("i+1")` still no change

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I guess then I ought to store the city variable inside the for loop, so that it stores it for each city?

Comment: By using i++ you increment the value stored in i by 1 as in your code `$(".city:eq("+i+++")").val()`. This is why the following line of code doesn't hide the appropriate element. `$(".city:eq("+i+1+")").css({'display':'none'});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For organized output: http://jsfiddle.net/mattblancarte/mnWH2/10/

```
var tr = $( 'tr' ),
    duplicates = [];

tr.each( function( k,v ){
  var elem = $( v ),
      child = elem.children().slice(0,1),
      city = child.text();

  if( $.inArray( city, duplicates ) > 0 ){
    child.empty();    
  } else {
    duplicates.push( city );
  }
});
```

For unorganized output: http://jsfiddle.net/mattblancarte/mnWH2/8/

```
$( 'tr' ).each( function( k,v ){
  var elem = $( v ),
      prev = elem.prev().children().slice(0,1).text(),
      child = elem.children().slice(0,1),
      city = child.text();

  if( prev === city ){
    child.empty();    
  } 
});
```

​

Note:: I don't think you want to use display:none;. This may shift the table around... Maybe visibility:hidden would be a better option. I just empty the cell.

Comment: OP didn't specify exactly what the HTML would be. I assumed it would be organized by city.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewBlancarte will take note on the display:none and thanks for the organized output bit, might need it later on.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should replace repeated city names with an empty space: http://jsfiddle.net/S2UNH/7/

```
var prev = "";  // cache previous value
$('#data').find("td.city").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).text().trim();
    if (val == prev) { // same value, blank it
        $(this).text(" ");
    } else {           // new value, store it
        prev = val; 
    }
});
```

How is this different from some of the other approaches posted so far:

- The list if cities do not need to be known in advance
- A city name is allowed to reappear further down the list as long as it is preceded by a different city. For example, see http://jsfiddle.net/S2UNH/8/. If all latter entry of NY is hidden irrespective of where it appears then viewers may mistake it for a TOKYO entry.

If you do want to *hide* repeated  values rather than replace them, then you'll need to place your text within another element since hiding the `<td>`tag would mess with your layout.

There are various ways of achieving this; here's one approach: http://jsfiddle.net/S2UNH/9/

Comment: It does not work if you have more than 2 similar city names. It clears up all but first.

Comment: @codef0rmer It should work for any number of repeated names: http://jsfiddle.net/S2UNH/5/

Answer (score 2):

If this is your data structure:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="city"><span>City</span></th>
            <th class="id"  ><span>Id  </span></th>
            <th class="name"><span>Name</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="city"><span>NY</span></td>
            <td class="id"  ><span>1</span></td>
            <td class="name"><span>James</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="city"><span>NY</span></td>   
            <td class="id"  ><span>2</span></td>     
            <td class="name"><span>John</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="city"><span>TOKYO</span></td>        
            <td class="id"  ><span>3</span></td>     
            <td class="name"><span>Jane</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="city"><span>TOKYO</span></td>     
            <td class="id"  ><span>4</span></td>     
            <td class="name"><span>June</span></td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
​
```

Then this code works:

```
var tr_no = $('.city').length;
for(i=0; i<tr_no; i++)  {
    if($(".city span").eq(i).text() == $(".city span").eq(i+1).text()){
        $(".city span").eq(i+1).css({'display':'none'});
    }
}
```

===

I coded the answer in a fiddler, since it is easier to verify:

http://jsfiddle.net/ewC6q/10/

Comment: Thanks @arkascha will try this out, its alot like my original code.

Comment: Had to initialize i to 0 to make it work with only two entries with same  city

Comment: Ok, thanks for the correction. I updated the fiddler and the answer above accordingly. Note that you also have to chance the "<=" into a "<".

Comment: Aha, true could actually do latter: change "<=" into "<". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can only assume you work on that data coded in a html table. 
If so than it might be that you have the strings as content of table cells:

```
<td class="city">NY</td>
```

Using css rules on table cells does not always work as expected, tables are somewhat special. You will have to wrap the content in a container each, maybe like this:

```
<td><span class="city">NY</span></td>
```

Not sure if this actually is your problem though, since your question is somewhat vague.

Comment: Thanks I have wrapped the content in a span, I maybe the loop and the condition are wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) jQuery selector which selects all elements that contain the specified text.

Try this code:

```
        // Storing the unique city names in an array
        var arrCity = {};
        $('table tr:gt(0) td:first-child').each(function () {
           arrCity[$(this).text()] = $(this).text(); 
        });

        // Removing the second city name for each cities
        $.each(arrCity, function (key, value) {
           $('table tr td:contains("' + value + '"):eq(1)').html('');
        });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/mnWH2/

Comment: This doesn't work with more than two duplicate values, I think.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mattblancarte/mnWH2/1/ That's the effect he wants, but that requires manual input for each city name. It should be dynamic.

Comment: @irrelephant, oh yeah thats what he was trying to do. I've updated the code above.

Comment: Perhaps you meant @MatthewBlancarte :-)

Comment: Thanks @irrelephant It works for manual input of the city, i needed it to be dynamic

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte is it possible to incorporate a loop such that it will check the whole table, and hide similar entries

Comment: Absolutely. I can post an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

i assumeed every tr has a class 'city',

```
$(function () {
    var prevCity = ''
    $('.city').each(function(){
        currCity = $(this).find('td:first').html().trim();
        if(currCity === prevCity)
        {
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
        }
        prevCity =  currCity;      
    });
});
```